# why is my wordpress not loading any images?

Tags: plugins, 404-error, https, nginx

I have installed wordpress on google compute engine..

Running nginx, wordpress and https.. The site doesn't load the admin panel or the images..

throws up 404 error on chrome inspection

> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET -
>   https://fadingfernphotography.ca/api/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/blog-1-1568x1046.png
>
> HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
>   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET -
>   https://fadingfernphotography.ca/api/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/Blog-1-1568x1263.png

Answer (score 1):

Given Link is not working but,

Links with HTTP works fine

http://fadingfernphotography.ca/api/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/blog-1-1568x1046.png

This is the problem of SSL.
Install SSL or change links to non https.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSL installed properly, and a http-to-https rewrite in your htaccess file, and the site was http but recently changed to https, you need to go through the posts database and change all http://www.exmaple.com to https://www.example.com (using your domain name).

The easiest way to do this is with a Search and Replace plugin. I like the "Better Search and Replace" plugin to easily do this. This will replace all references to your media files that are now http to https. And all will be well.

A backup of your database before any major changes is always a good idea.